# App Routing Re-directs to Login in Angular App When Choosing "Open Link in New Tab" Option in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have discovered an issue in my Angular 2 app that I'm trying to troubleshoot. Currently my routing works as expected when I click on links throughout my app. Here's an example of how routing paths are defined in my root routing file:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {contentId: 'home-page'} },
{ path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {contentId: 'contacts-page'} },
```

However, if while clicking on a link to route to a different component in the app, if I also right click my mouse and select "Open Link in New Tab", what happens is that, when the new tab opens, instead of loading the correct component, the page redirects to the login. Again, this ONLY happens when I choose the "Open Link in New Tab" option in Chrome.

The route for my login component looks like this:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
```

To clarify further, the only re-direct logic I have in the root routing file is to handle re-directing to the home component when a route isn't recognized:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

Here's an example of what the "contacts" link looks like - which is one of the routes listed above:
http://localhost:4200/contacts

Is this a default browser issue? Is it a default Angular issue? Just wondering how I track this down to address.

By the way, I thought this might be an AuthGuard issue, but even when I remove AuthGuard protection from the "contacts" link, that still re-directs to the login component when opened in a new tab.

Here is what my login component looks like:

```
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                private alertService: AlertService,
                private idle: Idle)
    {}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login(response)
    {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data =>
                {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    this.reset();
                },
                error =>
                {
                    this.alertService.error(error, response);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        this.authenticationService.username = this.model.username;
    }

    reset()
    {
        this.idle.watch();
        this.idleState = '';
        this.timedOut = false;
    }
}
```

The relevant code for the authenticationService being called here looks like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string)
{
    const u = encodeURIComponent(username);
    const p = encodeURIComponent(password);
    return this.http.post(this.url + this.ver + '/' + 'staff/login/' + u + '/' + p + '?' + this.key, {})
        .map((response: Response) =>
        {
            const user = response.json();
            if (user && (response.status = 200))
            {
                sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                console.log('User ' + this.username + ' successfully authenticated with API');

                // Track active user id
                this._userId = user.data._id;

                // Trigger login change
                this.change.emit(this);
            } else
            {
                console.log('User ' + this.username + ' not recognized by API');
            }
        });
}

isAuthenticated()
{
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

logout()
{
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    console.log('User successfully logged out');

    // Reset active user
    this._userId = undefined;

    // Trigger event
    this.change.emit(this);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the links look like?

Comment: `target:_blank` should work

Comment: But I don't want it to open in a new tab by default, I just want it to work if a user DOES choose to open in a new tab.

Comment: Are you using a location strategy?

Comment: Can you post your AuthenticationService?

Comment: Added authenticationService code above.

Comment: One more question: If you hit refresh do you have to re-login, or does that work as expected (user authentication data is retained)?

Comment: Re-fresh is no problem. Works as expected. Just reloads page in its last state.

Comment: Try changing sessionStorage to localStorage.  sessionStorage isn't persisted across tabs.  https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from discussion in comments:  In your AuthenticationService, change sessionStorage to localStorage.  sessionStorage only persists for the life of the tab.

Reference:  https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/